# Convert MPEG-4 codec to H.264 to play using Flask

Tags: html, flask, video, base64, codec

I want to play video on webpage using flask. But the video codec is mpeg-4 which is not supported by browsers. I want to convert codec of video to h.264 using python on server, is there any way to do it?

Here is my code snippets:

web_page.py

```
out_bytes = reply.content

zipped_file = io.BytesIO(out_bytes) 
with ZipFile(zipped_file, 'r') as zf:
   zf.printdir()      
   filename = zf.infolist()[0].filename
   buff = zf.read(filename)
   encoded = base64.b64encode(buff)#.decode('utf8')

return render_template('video_player.html', value = encoded )
```

video_player.html

```
<video autobuffer width="640" height="360" controls >
           <source type='video/mp4;  preload="auto" src="data:video/mp4;base64,{{value}}">
            Your browser does not support the video element.
        </video>
```

With the above code, I was only able to play audio on webpage, the video portion is blank.

Comment: There are many mpeg 4 codecs. In fact h.264 is an mpeg codec (Its mpeg4 part 10). You can use ffmpeg to convert anything to anything.

Comment: @szatmary ffmpeg is a seperate tool right? I want to convert codec inside my python file itself.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. There is no native python tools do that. They are all just wrappers around ffmpeg.

Comment: @szatmary, a wrapper can work for me. Is any you can recommend for python?